# Warning x error baddrawable when I run the deepmind DQN on GNOME (ubuntu 12)

Tags: gnome

It was scuccessful to run dqn with no image, but by trying using qlua (some tutorial) to see the netwrok playing the rom in real time, it gets a

Warning x error baddrawable 
It opens an image window but it is grey/blank and in terminal I get a " warning x error baddrawable (...)" error.

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE: I have solved the issue I was facing. Since I am running the DeepMind in one of my instances of Google Cloud V's, via a VNC GUI server, the proceedings should work in any. 
I´ve opened the script file (run_cpu) and put the line "export QT_GRAPHICSSYSTEM=native" right before the line that runs qlua. Let me share you my editings:

(UBUNTU 12.* using latest vncserver + GNOME GUI)
//terminal and where the dqn dir is:

$ vim run_cpu

//that opens the file 'run_cpu'. Press "i" to edit. The new edit should look like this (copy and paste at line 45):

export QT_GRAPHICSSYSTEM=native

//Press "ESC" then type ":wq" then enter.

$ reboot

//To make sure the effects will take change after restarting all processes.
Open a new SSH terminal via Google Cloud console. Before running the vncserver, also run the export QT_GRAPHICSSYSTEM=native before:

$ export QT_GRAPHICSSYSTEM=native
$ vncserver

Then, when connected thru a VNC client, open the terminal there and run ./run_cpu.

$ sudo bash ./run_cpu

//In case no root access.

UPDATE 2: I've also did a very small change at the dqn-graphics.sh. At line 4, leave nothing but the line with a 'then'. Like this ( :

//$ vim dqn-graphics.sh. Scroll at line 4. Press Enter. Put:
then

//ESC :wq