# X Error: BadDrawable (invalid Pixmap or Window parameter) when launching Apache on AMPPS

Tags: php, apache, ubuntu, ubuntu-16.04, ampps

After successfull instalation of Ampps on ubuntu 16.4 i encounterd error while starting it.
It showing blank screen and terminal started throwing below error.

```
X Error: BadDrawable (invalid Pixmap or Window parameter) 9
Major opcode: 62 (X_CopyArea)
Resource id: 0x1e00011
X Error: BadDrawable (invalid Pixmap or Window parameter) 9
Major opcode: 62 (X_CopyArea)
Resource id: 0x1e00011
```

After some research i found below solution.

add this line **QT_X11_NO_MITSHM=1** in system env var.

In my case environment file location is : etc/environment

I think this solution will also work for question [Warning x error baddrawable when I run the deepmind DQN on GNOME (ubuntu 12)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37151453/warning-x-error-baddrawable-when-i-run-the-deepmind-dqn-on-gnome-ubuntu-12)

Solution link is from https://github.com/P0cL4bs/WiFi-Pumpkin/issues/53